# How do we "partition" our web project using the MVC pattern?

Tags: php, model-view-controller, web-applications

I have to develop a webapp for my teacher that he'll use to manage his students.It has to do the following:

- Student Management (Registration, Registration validation, Deletion, .. etc)
- Attendance Management.
- A grade book, to keep track of every student's grades.
- Class management, since he teaches different classes, students must be "classified" into their corresponding classes.
- A basic login system.

The difficulty I am facing is how to "partition" this project using the MVC pattern? Should I do one model and one controller for every component of the app?

Or should I just use one controller and put all methods in it?

Does every controller I add to the app must have it's model?

I have fully understood what are the responsibilities of the model and the view and the controller,  but I can't wrap my head around how to use this pattern to "model" the application. Can you give me tips or clarifications about this? Maybe books I should read? etc ...

Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

Each component in the app should have its MVC equivalent. For instance you could have a StudentManagement Controller, Student Model and a folder that has all the views pertaining to the student. This encourages modular programming.

Comment: Is this your way of seeing it or is it how we actually use MVC pattern?

Comment: Usually most MVC frameworks do have specific folders that are named, controllers, models and view. So its just coding convention to name something like StudentManagementController or StudentController inside the controllers folder and likewise for the models and the views.